# GWT Compiler - only one permeation is building

Tags: gwt

I am running gwt-2.8.0-SNAPSHOT and have been running this for a while. I don't remember when it started happening or what caused it but my compilation is only building a single permutation. It is not compiling permutations for each browser. I did have the user-agent flag configured a while back but that has long since been removed. I have checked my pom.xml for any specific flags that might cause this to happen, I have checked other inherited modules for user.agent flags but can't seem to find anything. I have also enabled compilation ALL logging and don't see to find the issue. I am assuming gwt-2.8.0-SNAPSHOT is not configuring this option to only build a single permutation.

**Update 1**

I am compiling only the production module only. It was wisely pointed out by Adam that the collapse-all-properties which I use in development module will build a single compilation. This is not being picked up by the production module and for good measure I commented it out to make sure. I had an idea to add all the possible user.agents in the production module. When I did this I get the error that I user.agent cannot be redefined. I have a feeling that one of the inherited modules is setting this property. I tried setting loglevel to ALL to see if I could figure out which module is setting the property but no luck. I will keep digging until I figure out which module is causing this issue.

```
<define-property name="user.agent" values="ie8,gecko1_8,safari,ie9,ie10"></define-property>
```

**Update 2**

I found a temporary work around by just using the set-property for all the user.agents in the production module. I still don't know where this property would be getting set. I went through some of the inherited modules but was unable to find the culprit.

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8,gecko1_8,safari,ie9,ie10"></set-property>
```

**Common Module**

The common module is shared between the development and production modules. It has all inherits and common definitions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.place.Place" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.activity.Activity" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.inject.Inject' />


    <inherits name="gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialWithJQuery" />
    <inherits name="gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialTableDebug" />
    <inherits name="gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialDesignBasic" />
    <inherits name="gwt.material.design.addins.GwtMaterialAddins" />
    <inherits name="gwt.material.design.themes.GwtMaterialThemeBlue" />

    <inherits name="com.googlecode.gwt.charts.Charts" />

    <!-- Maps -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.maps.Maps' />

    <!-- Maybe remove -->

    <inherits name='com.google.common.base.Base' />
    <inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect" />
    <inherits name="com.google.common.util.concurrent.Concurrent" />
    <inherits name="com.google.common.cache.Cache" />

    <inherits name='com.googlecode.gflot.GFlotJQueryNoConflict' />
    <inherits name="org.fusesource.restygwt.RestyGWT" />

    <!-- Adding temporal support -->
    <replace-with class="com.upsnap.dsp.web.client.temporal.ChronoUnit">
        <when-type-is class="java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit" />
    </replace-with>

    <public path='view/resource'>
        <include name='css/*.css' />
        <include name='js/*.js' />
    </public>

    <set-property name="restygwt.autodetect.plainText" value="true" />

    <!-- This is so gflot doesn't fail This should almost assuredly be disabled 
        for production -->
    <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag'
        value='false' />


    <!-- May be dangerous, do some more investigation 8-2016 -->
    <!-- <set-configuration-property name="compiler.enum.obfuscate.names" value="true" 
        /> -->

    <!-- Enabling GSS will tell the GWT compiler to use GSS for all CssResource 
        interfaces. This flag can either be “false” (default) or “true”. -->
    <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.enableGss"
        value="true" />

    <!-- If GSS is enabled and the GWT compiler finds a .css file, it will first 
        convert this file to gss and then feed it into GSS on the fly. Gradual GSS 
        migration -->
    <set-configuration-property name="CssResource.conversionMode"
        value="strict" />

    <source path='client' />
</module>
```

**Production Module**

The is is the production module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='dsp'>

    <inherits name="com.upsnap.dsp.web.DspCommon" />

    <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO" />

    <set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="strip" />

    <!-- Form Factor support -->
    <replace-with class="com.upsnap.dsp.web.client.DesktopInjectorProvider">
        <when-type-is class="com.upsnap.dsp.web.client.InjectorProvider" />
    </replace-with>

</module>
```

**Development Module**

This is the development module used for debugging etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='dsp'>

    <inherits name="com.upsnap.dsp.web.DspCommon" />

    <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINE" />

    <set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
    <set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames"
        value="true" />
    <set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers"
        value="true" />

    <collapse-all-properties />

    <!-- Form Factor support -->
    <replace-with class="com.upsnap.dsp.web.client.DesktopInjectorProvider">
        <when-type-is class="com.upsnap.dsp.web.client.InjectorProvider" />
    </replace-with>

</module>
```

**POM**

pom.xml excerpt for gwt plugin.

```
<configuration>
    <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
    <disableClassMetadata>true</disableClassMetadata>
    <style>PRETTY</style>
    <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
    <runTarget>dsp.html</runTarget>
    <hostedWebapp>${war.directory}</hostedWebapp>
    <webappDirectory>${war.directory}</webappDirectory>
    <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
    <localWorkers>4</localWorkers>
    <modules><module>com.upsnap.dsp.web.DevelopmentDesktop</module>
    </modules>
    <extraJvmArgs>-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -Dgwt.compiler.enableClosureCompiler=true</extraJvmArgs>
</configuration>
```

**Output**

This is the output from the compilation Notice that there is only 1 permutation being built.

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0-SNAPSHOT:compile (default) @ dsp-web ---
[INFO] Loading inherited module 'com.upsnap.dsp.web.DevelopmentDesktop'
[INFO]    Loading inherited module 'com.upsnap.dsp.web.DspCommon'
[INFO]       Loading inherited module 'gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialWithJQuery'
[INFO]          Loading inherited module 'gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialDesignBase'
[INFO]             [WARN] Line 45: Setting configuration property named 'CssResource.legacy' in module 'gwt.material.design.GwtMaterialDesignBase' that has not been previously defined
[INFO] Compiling module com.upsnap.dsp.web.DevelopmentDesktop
[INFO]    Ignored 9 units with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.upsnap.dsp.web.client.rest.ExtraCodecs.ErrorResponseCodec'
[INFO]       Rebinding com.upsnap.dsp.web.client.rest.ExtraCodecs.ErrorResponseCodec
[INFO]          Invoking generator org.fusesource.restygwt.rebind.JsonEncoderDecoderGenerator
[INFO]             Generating: com.upsnap.dsp.web.client.rest.ExtraCodecs_ErrorResponseCodec_Generated_ExtendedJsonEncoderDecoder_
[INFO]                checking: org.fusesource.restygwt.client.JsonEncoderDecoder, type: class com.google.gwt.dev.javac.typemodel.JParameterizedType
[INFO]    Compiling 1 permutation
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 0...
[INFO]    Compile of permutations succeeded
[INFO]    Compilation succeeded -- 33.295s
[INFO] Linking into /Users/chinshaw/devel/workspace/upsnap/dsp/modules/web/target/dsp-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/dsp
[INFO]    Invoking Linker Cross-Site-Iframe
[INFO]       Ignoring the following script tags in the gwt.xml file
[INFO] jquery-1.8.3.min.js
[INFO] jquery-noconflict.js
[INFO] 
[INFO]    Link succeeded
[INFO]    Linking succeeded -- 0.174s
[INFO]
```

Comment: After your update, check the file `compilation-mappings.txt` in your compiled module. It should contain compiled *.js file names mapped to user-agent values.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using `<collapse-all-properties />`. It means that, instead of generating permutations for each user-agent, it generates only one permutation for all user-agents.

Comment: I needed to add this to the description. I am compiling the production module only which does not contain the collapse-all-properties. I also tried commenting this out to see if it would make a difference but it did not. I tried adding the  <define-property name="user.agent" values="ie8,gecko1_8,safari,ie9,ie10"></define-property> to the production module to get it to try and force a compilation of all the modules but this gave me the error that I cannot redefine user.agent. This leads me to believe that one of the inherited modules is defining this configuration.

Comment: The log you're showing is about the development module though.